# How to explain the huge difference between Fabric crashes and Xcode crashes?

Tags: ios, xcode, crashlytics, google-fabric

We have an app live with thousands of daily users. We released a new version in phases, where the current 2% phase is paused.

We use fabric/crashlytics for logging the crashes. The Environment class is reading data from the Keychain, and is developed by ourselves. The error of the crash is `errSecInteractionNotAllowed`.

Fabric reports 121 crashes in our Environment class on version 2.1.2, while XCode only reports 3 crashes on the same version.

The only reason we can think of: We read something about iOS calling the app in the background while automatically updating the app. When the device is locked during the update, the Keychain will be locked as well. This would result in a crash. It might happen that Apple doesn't report this crash, since it is caused by the Apple updating system.

Is there any other clue that explains the difference between Fabric and XCode crashes?

[image: fabric]

[image: xcode]

Comment: XCode is in the last 2 weeks. Did you set the same filter on Fabrics? I think that Apple & Fabrics don't have the same "refresh/update" time of the theses logs.

Comment: @Larme 2.1.2 was released only two days ago, so last two weeks should be sufficient..

Answer (score 6):

To see the Xcode crashes, users have to explicitly enable a setting  "Share crash reports with apple and developers" (I think thats what its called) either during phone setup or later on via iOS settings app. If they don't enable it, you won't see anything. Most people I know don't enable it as they are worried about privacy.

Crashlytics doesn't require users to agree to sending reports. So its extremely likely crashlytics will report a higher volume of crashes.

Comment: I totally agree dat the Crashlytics number will probably be higher than the Xcode number. 3 vs 121 is a huge difference though, I can't imagine that 97.5% has the setting on, right?

Comment: @harmjanr you mean 97.5% didn't turn on the setting right? I've released many apps in the past, I recall only ever seeing a handful of Xcode crashes and thousands of crashlytics crashes. We got more complaints via reviews complaining about crashes than we saw on xcode crashes. With an opt-in style approach, only displayed once when you turn on the phone for the first time, and not a particularly great explanation for why you should ... most will not turn it on. Looking at your two screenshots is exactly what I would expect to see.